# update two fields with same attributes but different function Argument

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am pretty new to Selenium Python and I am automating one task.  In my Task, I need to enter a password in two fields - 'Password' and 'Confirm Password'

I am using `send_keys` to pass password text.  But My issue is Both fields has same attributes and attributes are generated dynamically.  Below are the HTML element of both fields.

**Password Field**

```
<input size="12" id="mx-pw-1560134066" onblur="this.onkeyup();" value="" onkeyup="MxTableOnChangeText(this, 'CREDENTIAL_comhpmvcduiviewCreateVCDomainGroupAction1484904977993', '09USE939SBK9', 5)" type="PASSWORD">
```

**Confirm-Password Field**

```
<input size="12" id="mx-pw-1337668046" onblur="this.onkeyup();" value="" onkeyup="MxTableOnChangeText(this, 'CREDENTIAL_comhpmvcduiviewCreateVCDomainGroupAction1484904977993', '09USE939SBK9', 6)" type="PASSWORD">
```

The numbers in the ID field are dynamically generated. onblur is same for both.  Only difference I could see in these html between two fields is the last argument of the `MxTableOnChangeText`. FOr Password field it is 5, and for confirm Password, It is 6.  So based on the Arguments I need to pass the values.

For that I tried to use wildcards inside method Arguments like below. But I am getting Error.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[matches(@onkeyup,"MxTableOnChangeText(this,*,*,5)")').send_keys('password')
```

Kindly help me how to Handle dynamic IDs or How to use wildcards inside Method arguments.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling dynamically generated `id` seem to be unacceptable in your case as string base of `id` (`mx-pw-`) is the same for both fields. The easy way to select both elements is to use index:

```
password = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="PASSWORD"]')[0]
confirm_password = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="PASSWORD"]')[1]
```

Or you can use `onkeyup` attribute like this:

```
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@onkeyup, ", 5)")]')
confirm_password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@onkeyup, ", 6)")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one alternative way if your `id` is dynamic, `mx-pw` fixed and only number getting change -

```
// for password

driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[starts-with(@id, "mx-pw")][1]')

// for confirm password

driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[starts-with(@id, "mx-pw")][2]')
```